# How to execute code after a button is clicked in modal

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

After the button "confirm" is clicked, I want to perform those operations. but my code doesn't run after the line `if (isset($_POST['confirm'])){..}
i would really appreaciate your help.

```
echo "<div class='container'>
    <form action='confirm.php' method='post'>
    <center><button type='button' name='confirm' value='confirm' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Confirm</button></center>
    </form>
    <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' role='dialog'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>";


 if (isset($_POST['confirm'])){

        $query2 = "SELECT status FROM reserver WHERE picker='$picking' AND droper='$droping'";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
        $row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
        $check_status=$row1['status'];
        if($check_status=='available')
        {

         $query3 = "UPDATE reserver SET status='reserved' WHERE picker='$picking' AND droper='$droping'";
         if(mysqli_query($conn, $query3)){



 echo " <div class='modal-content'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
      <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
      <h4 class='modal-title'>Confirmation</h4>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
      <p>Confirmed Sucessfully!</p>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-footer'>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>";
         }
        }
      else  {
            echo " <div class='modal-content'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
      <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
      <h4 class='modal-title'>Notice</h4>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
      <p>Unavailable Vehicle!</p>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-footer'>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>";
        }

 }
```

EDIT : now i have an else case for diaplaying unavailable vehicle

Comment: you understand that PHP is a server side language and you are looking at a client side interaction? You need to use javascript to bind an event to the button click event and if you need to run some php you need to use ajax

Comment: can you suggest the code for correction here?

Comment: As @LelioFaieta said, I think the best way is using Ajax. The idea will be : in JS, when someone CLICK on your btn, you will make an AJAX call. 1/ You get the data you want in JS then you send this data to your PHP with AJAX 2/ You use your data in your PHP to do what you want. 3/ In your ajax call you can get data if it success or fail to know what happen. Good luck !

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: It’s not a matter of fixing your code but to rewrite it completely to use JavaScript and Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will not open the modal with success message. You can try something like this [Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/iD5w79hr)

```
<?php
$status = false;
if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {

    $check_status = 'available';
    $query2 = "SELECT status FROM reserver WHERE picker='$picking' AND droper='$droping'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
    $check_status=$row1['status'];
    if($check_status=='available')
    {
        $query3 = "UPDATE reserver SET status='reserved' WHERE picker='$picking' AND droper='$droping'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $query3)) {
            $status = true;
        }
    }
}
?>
<div class='container'>
    <form action='confirm.php' method='post'>
        <center><button type='submit' name='confirm' value='confirm'>Confirm</button></center>
        <button type='button' name='confirm' value='confirm' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' style="display:none;">Confirm</button>
    </form>
    <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' role='dialog'>
        <div class='modal-dialog'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                    <h4 class='modal-title'>Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                    <p>Confirmed Sucessfully!</p>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-footer'>
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php if( $status == true ): ?>
    <script>
        $('.btn.btn-info').trigger('click');
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This absolutely works fine. Thank you!
But now i need an else case also. I have edited the codes. i added 14 to 15 lines of code from last

Comment: still using msqli in 2018 ? I strongly discourage any use of msqli, you should learn to use PDO

Answer (score 1):

However what you want to do if you want to submit data and process it by php you need to use `<input type='submit'/>` not button.

`<input type="button" />` work with javascript and will not submit a form.
`<input type="submit" />` will submit the form.

but AJAX is here to do this for you just you to learn some basics to do that and is much easier with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)

So here is example how that works

**First thing you need is to create a simple HTML form**

if you want append some data

```
<form method="POST" id="my_form">
<input type="hidden" name='test'/>
<input type="button" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

OR just create a simple button

```
<button id="click me" id="click_me"></button>
```

and then create a another HTML element to show user response status

```
<div id="response"></div>
```

**Good. So now we finish our html code let's go to write some jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#click_me").click(function() {
$.ajax({
url : "your_php_file.php", // file path you want to send data
type : "POST",
data : {},
success : function(data) {
     $("#response").html("Confirmed Sucessfully!");
}
});
});
});
```

**And the last thing is your php code**

```
<?php
if() {
// your php code
}else{
header("HTTP/2.0 400 Bad request");
}
?>
```

This is just a simple explain quickly how to handle AJAX request. You need to learn more about this to build secure and useful web application

Comment: Thanks for the explainations. It indeed helped me with the basics.

Comment: @aadil good for you. If my answer helped you don't forget to vote up/check